# Yii2 - Undefined variable in View file

Tags: variables, yii2, undefined

I am trying to pass the variable to view the page through the siteController, however when I try, I always get the error undefined Variable.

Here is my code in the siteController:

```
public function actionIndex(){

        $Opere = Opere::find()->all();
        return $this->render('index', [
            'titolo' => $titolo, 'tecnica' => $tecnica, 'misura' => $misura, 'anno' => $anno,
            'prezzo' => $prezzo, 'note' => $note, 'url_grandi' => $url_grandi]);
    }
```

and here below is the code on the index page:

```
<?php foreach ($Opere as $o): //var_dump($o); ?>
          <div class='grid-item'>
              <img src='<?php $url_grandi;?>' class='grid-item-img'/>
              <div class='grid-item-overlay'>
                <div class='text'>
                  <div class='innerText'>
                    Titolo:  <?php $titolo;?><br />
                    Tecnica:  <?php $tecnica;?><br />
                    Misura:   <?php $misura;?><br />
                    Anno:  <?php  $anno;?><br />
                    Prezzo: &euro;  <?php $prezzo;?><br />
                    Note: <?php $note;?>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Because You didn`t define any variables in your controller! now you send nothing to your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I added the incorrect variable in my foreach loop. I was trying to call the variable $titolo, however, in my foreach loop I had specified that the variable $titolo as $o. This is why it did not recognize the variable $titolo.

The following below is the correct code string to output the db data:

```
<?= $o->titolo;?>
```

and not:

```
<?php echo $titolo;?>
```

hope this helps someone else with a similar problem.